# Java Jpeg Decoder

Tags: java, jpeg

I have a task to modify JPEG format with dynamic Huffman. So I'm trying to find source code of simple Jpeg Decoder written in Java. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since C/C++ code is faster than Java code executing, you will probably find source code to do this task more easily by searching for C/C++ libraries for this purpose. However, since C/C++ have many similarities with Java, it might be a good starting point to get in touch with the algorithms used and a general idea of the architecture.

You can find an example of a library for this purpose at:

http://www.subquantumtech.com/jpeg/

Comment: asked for java not for c/c++

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103649-adaptive-huffman/

and this one: http://en.pudn.com/downloads93/sourcecode/zip/detail364515_en.html (links to the files are at the bottom of the page)